# Trouble connecting from docker container with ASP.NET core to SQL Server container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have a container deploying a front end in ASP.NET Core trying to connect to the backend SQL Server  database. I am running windows 10 with Docker desktop v19.03.13.

The website container is built on

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./FOOBAR/*.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FOOBAR.dll"]
```

The database is built on

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
USER root
COPY setup.sql setup.sql
COPY import-data.sh import-data.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

Everything works marvelous when running outside docker, .NET, Python, SQL Server Management Studio.

In .NET, my connection string is:

```
Server=localhost;Database=FOOBAR;Integrated Security=True
```

In Python:

```
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=localhost;database=FOOBAR;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

So I need to deploy this to a network that does not have a domain controller so I need to handle all database authentication.

When I build my containers, I change my .NET connection string to

```
dbConnection="Server=host.docker.internal;Database=FOOBAR;User Id=sa;Password=Password1!;"
```

I spawn my containers with

```
docker run -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=Password1! -p 1433:1433 -v c:\temp\:/var/opt/mssql/data --name foobar_db -d foobar_db:1.0
docker run -p 8080:80 --name foobar --link foobar_db:foobar_db -d foobar:1.0
```

My containers spin up, my database is deployed just fine.  From the host, I can use SQL Server Management Studio and Python, and connect to my database container using the credentials above, and connect and perform read/writes perfectly.

When I connect from the .NET using

```
Server=host.docker.internal;Database=FOOBAR;User Id=sa;Password=Password1!;
```

I can see my SQL Server container complain about an invalid login,

> Login failed for user '6794cfd81d48\Guest'

where I can confirm that `6794cfd81d48` is the hash of my SQL Server container, `foobar_db`.

IIS serves up webpages just fine, the problem is connecting to the database.  Even though I am providing the correct username and password, I am unable to connect from another container to the SQL Server container because it thinks that I am a guest to that container. Depending on the deployment environment, normally I would create SQL Server logins, either for a machine or for a user, but not in this case.

Comment: `Trusted_connection` and `username/password` are mutually exclusive, which one do you want? If you want to login as `sa` you need `trusted_connection=no`. That is to say, `trusted_connection` means using Kerberos/NTLM to authenticate, not a username/password combo

Comment: Sorry.  I edited above.  I forgot to mention that we developed all of our services and now we have been told to deploy this to a small enclave that does not have a windows domain controller so we are having to handle all the authentication until the system is more matured and past concept phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an offending IT security software application that was identified as the cause.  IT set a passthrough so the docker applications could by the security and everything worked as designed.